# How can I create a loop with variable criteria/condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that loops through X sheets to count how many meet a certain criteria, but I want this criteria to be variable.

This is my code for the function:

```
Function f_1(Condition As Variant, Condition_TrueFalse As Boolean, i_Start As Long, i_End As Long) As Long
    f_1 = 0
    For i = i_Start To i_End
        Select Case Condition
            Case Condition_TrueFalse
                f_1 = Application.Sum(f_1, 1)
        End Select
    Next i
End Function
```

I have a workbook with 20 worksheets, with the names "WorksheetNumber1", "WorksheetNumber2", "WorksheetNumber3", "WorksheetNumber4", ..., "WorksheetNumber20".

So, for example, I might have this subroutine:

```
Sub(Workbook1 As Workbook)
    Dim count As Long

    'example A
    count = f_1(IsEmpty(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Cell(1,1)),False,1,10)
    MsgBox(count)

    'example B
    count = f_1(Application.CountA(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Range("$C$3:$E$5"))>0,True,1,5)
    MsgBox(count)
End Sub
```

I have multiple of these criteria, so I really don't want to repeat the code; since the structure of the code is similar, I thought I might be able to make the criteria variable.

What I want is:

- For Example A, if cell(1,1) is not empty for WorksheetNumber**i** (for i = 1 To 10), then f_1 goes up by one; the final value for f_1 is returned and assigned to the variable 'count'; and then 'count' is displayed.
- For Example B, if the count of non-empty cells in range $C$3:$E$5 is greater than 0 for WorksheetNumber**i** (for i = 1 To 5), then the f_1 goes up by one; the final value for f_1 is returned and assigned to the variable 'count'; and then 'count' is displayed.

Currently, I'm running into a "Subscript Out of Range" error, in the "count = ..." lines of code, which I'm guessing is because of the 'i' in Worksheets("SheetNumber" & i). How might I go about coding to achieve the results I want?

Thank you so much!

Comment: In Example 1 you have `Cell(1,1)`, should be `Cells(1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Provided all of your tests can be expressed as worksheet formulas then you can do something like this:

```
Sub tester()

    Debug.Print CountIt(ThisWorkbook, "A1<>""""", 1, 5)

    Debug.Print CountIt(ThisWorkbook, "COUNTA(C3:E5)>0", 1, 5)

    Debug.Print CountIt(ThisWorkbook, "CountRedFont(B3:B5)", 1, 5)

End Sub

Function CountIt(wb As Workbook, theTest As String, _
                fromSheet As Long, toSheet As Long) As Long
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    For i = fromSheet To toSheet
        n = n + IIf(wb.Sheets(i).Evaluate(theTest), 1, 0)
    Next i
    CountIt = n
End Function

'test UDF
Function CountRedFont(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, n As Long
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Font.Color = vbRed Then n = n + 1
    Next c
    CountRedFont = n
End Function
```